# Creating a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have code that generates a list of 28 dictionaries. It cycles thru 28 files and links data points from each file in the appropriate dictionary. In order to make my code more flexible I wanted to use:

```
tegDics = [dict() for x in range(len(files))]
```

But when I run the code the first 27 dictionaries are blank and only the last, tegDics[27], has data. Below is the code including the clumsy, yet functional, code I'm having to use that generates the dictionaries:

```
x=0
import os
files=os.listdir("DirPath")
os.chdir("DirPath")
tegDics = [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}] # THIS WORKS!!!
#tegDics = [dict() for x in range(len(files))] - THIS WON'T WORK!!!
allRads=[]
while x<len(tegDics): # now builds dictionaries 
    for line in open(files[x]):
        z=line.split('\t')
        allRads.append(z[2])
        tegDics[x][z[2]]=z[4] # pairs catNo with locNo
    x+=1
```

Does anybody know why the more elegant code doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're using `x` within the list comprehension, it will no longer be zero by the time you reach the `while` loop - it will be `len(files)-1` instead. I suggest changing the variable you use to something else. It's traditional to use a single underscore for a value you don't care about.

```
tegDics = [dict() for _ in range(len(files))]
```

---

It could be useful to eliminate your use of `x` entirely. It's customary in python to iterate directly over the objects in a sequence, rather than using a counter variable. You might do something like:

```
for tegDic in tegDics:
    #do stuff with tegDic here
```

Although it's slightly trickier in your case, since you want to simultaneously iterate through `tegDics` and `files` at the same time. You can use `zip` to do that.

```
import os
files=os.listdir("DirPath")
os.chdir("DirPath")
tegDics = [dict() for _ in range(len(files))]
allRads=[]
for file, tegDic in zip(files,tegDics):
    for line in open(file):
        z=line.split('\t')
        allRads.append(z[2])
        tegDic[z[2]]=z[4] # pairs catNo with locNo
```

Comment: Nice find! I missed that `x` was reused. You should teach the OP about the `for each` nature of Python loops as well, with a touch of `enumerate()` or `zip()`.

Comment: Didn't know about _ convention, suppose a bit dangerous to mix with gettext habits though

Comment: Feel free to break away from the convention if you're worried about mixups like that. I also like to use `i` as my "variable that is never used for anything other than `range` loops".

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that in py3 comprehension don't leak their variables.

Answer (score -2):

Anyway there is a simplest way imho:

```
taegDics = [{}]*len(files)
```

Comment: This has a surprising effect, though. If you try `dicts = [{}]*2; dicts[0][0]=99; print dicts`, you'll see that _both_ dictionaries have a `99` entry, even though you only set one!

Comment: Damn! this is very bad. Thanks for your warning.